# Android Virtual Device super slow - pc too slow?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, hardware

if I wanna work/test with my AVD, the Android emulator is super slow, barely usable. Im developing with eclipse and was just about testing a helloWorld app., but the whole thing runs too slow. Is it the hardware of my pc?
details:

```
AMD Athlon 64 3500+, 2.21 Ghz
2 GB RAM
Windows XP
```

I know its kinda running with coal, but actually, its just a phone emulator. What is your opinion?

Comment: That PC is not really state of the art. I'd suggest upgrading it: more RAM and (at least) a dual-core CPU would *definitely* help for *any* kind of software development.

Comment: if your commercially developing on this PC then that's trying to save money at the wrong places! [This question on programmers.se](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/93983/why-dont-all-companies-buy-developers-the-best-hardware) might help you with telling it to your boss on your own.

Comment: im just a student worker, but your absolutely right, of course. Its a actually a bit embarrassing to have an athlon 3500+, no doubt about that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem. The emulator was slow as hell. You can significantly speed it up by changing the heap size allocated to it in AVD manager. Go to AVD Manager -> Select your device -> Click on "Details" button. The heap size will most probably be 24 or 48 (vm.heapSize: 24). Here's how you increase the heap size.

**AVD Manager -> Select device -> Edit -> Hardware section (same window) -> Select "Max VM application heapsize" property -> Double click and edit the value to 512 or higher.**

Restart the emulator (if already running).

Comment: This is the real correct answer, people. The spirit of the question is to figure out whether the emulator's performance can be improved, and it can be by following the instructions here.

Answer (score 3):

It is just a very slow emulator. The best option is definately to test on a real phone.

Comment: Android-x86 inside a VirtualBox is considerably faster, btw.

Comment: i will try this. Thanks to all of you guys!

Answer (score 1):

I am using Intel Core2 Quad @ 2.33HZ, 2.33Hz with 3GB of RAM. It take about 20 seconds to upload the app after making changes. You must upgrade your PC in order to test your apps on emulator. If you have android device, then good. Your PC will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Like cjk says, the emulator is incredibly slow. It fully emulates the core ARM architecture and can only be single threaded. Best you can do to help it is assign it to a lesser used core and increase the priority/niceness of the process.

Comment: Unfortunately the Athlon 64 3500+ is a single-core processor.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same type of specs on my computer while developing, indeed the emulator is too slow to work with. What is your screen resolution? In my case connecting to a monitor sped up the emulator, really lame..

Comment: my res. is 1280 x 1024. you mean a smaller or a larger monitor speeds it up?

Comment: Larger, but since yours is as high as mine, I think the emulator is to heavy to run on your specs.

Answer (score 0):

My LCD's current screen resolution is 1600 * 900 and I am using Windows 7. Its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have a macbook air (not very powerfull), the emulator was too slow. It was because the in the Emulation Options Use Host GPU was ticked. This might also help. its fine with:

Device: 3.2" QVGA
target: level 8
Memory Ram: 512
Heap: 128
Emulation options: not ticked.

hope it helps